# Parameterized test using custom objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to write a Parameterized test for my add method for Binary Search tree
I wrote the test method:

```
void add() {
    student5 =  new Student("student5", LocalDate.of(2000,5,12), "none");
    studentSet2.add(student5);
    assertAll(
            ()->assertThat(studentSet2).contains(student5),
            ()->assertThat(studentSet2).hasSize(1),
            ()->assertThat(studentSet2.iterator().next()).isEqualTo(student5),
            ()->assertThat(studentSet2.toArray(new Student[1])).containsOnly(student5)
    );
```

This is my current test method but i want to transform it using parameterized test.But when i started to learn about it ,i found that he can take only strings and primitiv types.
Can i write something for my test method to take a "Student" object as parameter?

Comment: I think you can specify source of parameterized test to be a method returning a stream of objects. Read here for more information https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Comment: _"to write a Parameterized test for my add method for Binary Search tree"_ where is your binary tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want create a lot of synthetic cases (or read from somewhere...), for example

```
static Stream<Arguments> testAddToAListSource() {
    final List<String> baseData = List.of("one", "two", "three");
    
    // construct cases using a base list and adding null or a new element
    return IntStream.range(0, baseData.size() + 1)
            .mapToObj(n -> baseData.stream().limit(n).collect(toList()))
            .flatMap(xs -> Stream.of(null, "extra", "superExtra")
                .map(x -> arguments(new ArrayList<>(xs), x)));
}
```

this method create pairs of a list of strings and a new string to add.

Suppose you want to verify that this element is correctly added to the list checking the following invariants

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testAddToAListSource")
void testAddToAList(List<String> caseList, String newElement) {

    // count elements
    final long currentSize = caseList.size();

    // count how many times the element is in list
    final long currentTimes = caseList.stream().filter(e -> Objects.equals(e, newElement)).count();

    // add
    caseList.add(newElement);

    // count elements
    final long newSize = caseList.size();

    // count how many times the element is in list
    final long newTimes = caseList.stream().filter(e -> Objects.equals(e, newElement)).count();

    assertEquals(newSize, currentSize + 1);
    assertEquals(newTimes, currentTimes + 1);
}
```

with output

[image]

in your specific case I don't know what type is `studentSet2` but probably you could change your `add` signature to

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testAdd")
void add(StudentSet studentSet2, Student student5) {
    ...
```

and create a provider like

```
static Stream<Arguments> testAdd() {
    ...
```